# JAVA Spring MVC - HTTP status 404 - RequestMapping isn't working

Tags: java, spring, dispatcher

I began to learn Spring MVC and I have a problem with my app. When I type: "http://localhost:8080/addcat" in my browser, it returns 404 status.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="application, dao, model, controllers" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class CatController {

    @Autowired
    private CatDAO catDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String Index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addcat", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addCat(Model model) {
        return "addCat";
    }

}
```

I work on Tomcat v7.0. Routing isn't working for any option - for "/" also.

EDIT:
After few changes, I have logs from Tomcat:

```
paź 04, 2015 10:28:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.0.RELEASE;;.
paź 04, 2015 10:28:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:kotki-webapp' did not find a matching property.
paź 04, 2015 10:28:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
paź 04, 2015 10:28:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
paź 04, 2015 10:28:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1037 ms
paź 04, 2015 10:28:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
paź 04, 2015 10:28:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
paź 04, 2015 10:28:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
paź 04, 2015 10:28:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
paź 04, 2015 10:28:22 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Oct 04 22:28:23 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kotyController' defined in file [C:\Users\Maciej\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\kotki-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\controllers\KotyController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class controllers.KotyController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [controllers.KotyController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [controllers.KotyController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ldao/KotDAO;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:707)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:649)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:330)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dao.KotDAO
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 30 more

paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kotyController' defined in file [C:\Users\Maciej\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\kotki-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\controllers\KotyController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class controllers.KotyController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [controllers.KotyController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [controllers.KotyController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ldao/KotDAO;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:707)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:649)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:330)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dao.KotDAO
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 30 more

paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kotyController' defined in file [C:\Users\Maciej\Java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\kotki-webapp\WEB-INF\classes\controllers\KotyController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class controllers.KotyController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [controllers.KotyController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [controllers.KotyController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ldao/KotDAO;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:707)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:649)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:330)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dao.KotDAO
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 30 more

paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/kotki-webapp] startup failed due to previous errors
paź 04, 2015 10:28:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
paź 04, 2015 10:28:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
paź 04, 2015 10:28:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
paź 04, 2015 10:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3906 ms
```

**My catalogue structure: http://postimg.org/image/whqpqckpn/**

Comment: You have to add the war name between `http://localhost:8080/` and `addcat`

Comment: War name? What is that in that exact situation?

Comment: @Jens, is there another way to avoid that? That was mentioned on another post but I have a war packaged app right now that seems to resolve `http://localhost:8080/` but I can't seem to find the config difference in the posts.

Comment: May be the controller isn't scanned by Spring .. I'm not sure but i think that you must provide the full package name  in **component-scan** ( x.y.z.controllers )

Comment: @MouradZouabi it is actually full package name, because file CatController is in src/main/java/controllers

Comment: try to add a method with  a dummy log and annotate it with **@PostConstruct** to check wether le controller is loaded or not

Comment: I've add logs from Tomcat in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class
[controllers.KotyController] for resource metadata: could not find
class that it depends on
```

Your controller depends on CatDAO, so it seems the problem is either with CatDAO class not having spring annotation in place to mark it as bean or not being in "dao" package. It might be a misspelling also, as you also seem to have an error message about "dao.KotDAO" class as well. You haven't listed your project file structure so we can't tell which it is.

Comment: I've added image with my project file structure.